# Tensorflow 1.15 not detecting GPU on GPU enabled Kaggle kernels

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, kaggle

I want to use matterplot's MaskRCNN library: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN. This uses tensorflow (v1.x) implementation of MaskRCNN where as my machine has the upgraded Tensorflow (v2.0). So I'm trying to first downgrade the TF version and the checking whether the GPU is available or not using `tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available()`, but this is returning False. Here is my kernel just for checking this: https://www.kaggle.com/kaushal2896/tensorflow-version-test

However when I do the same process on Google Colab, it's working fine. Here is my Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ecBB8Zzc4H0EXCZJ79dbjObgdXpHAT1H#scrollTo=PSTHIweDZzvS&line=1&uniqifier=1

I've also referred this answer: [Tensorflow 2.0rc not detecting GPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728052/tensorflow-2-0rc-not-detecting-gpus). As mentioned in the step to check whether the TensorFlow can access the GPU or not, it returns False but on Colab, it returns True.

I've also tried running following piece of code on both Kaggle kernel and Google Colab notebook:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

This returns following output in Kaggle kernel:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 16110875363616681113
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 4887609401225506649
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 15252770185025289462
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

The same code returns following on colab:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 9801969460581293108
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 12457376035032350067
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 13999524601515353878
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 15956161332
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 6402597460949153193
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0"
]
```

But I'm not sure what this means. What am I missing here? Why there is different behaviour for same TensorFlow version?

Comment: Did you find a way to downgrade TF in Kaggle kernels?

Comment: @VincentYong Nope. But this might help: https://www.kaggle.com/c/imaterialist-fashion-2020-fgvc7/discussion/142828. Also it was working on Google colab, so you can try there.